# I want to fetch value from mysql db and show it in dropdown box in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am able to fetch value normally but it is not rendering in dropdown box or even textbox. Plz help. Thankx in advance.

```html
    <tr class="rows">
    <td width="150">
    Application Name:
    </td>
    <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="applicationName" path="applicationName">
    <option value="${applicationname}"></option>
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="GHI">GHI</option>
    <option value="JKL">JKL</option>
    <option value="MNO">MNO</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       ${applicationname}
    </td>
    </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: I am using spring mvc hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td>
    <select class="form-control" name="applicationName" path="applicationName">
    <option value="${applicationname}">${applicationname}</option>
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="GHI">GHI</option>
    <option value="JKL">JKL</option>
    <option value="MNO">MNO</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much.... Such a wonderful person you are... I wasted a day in such a small thing.. Appreciate your help!!!